# ssh -X: Remote application should open hyperlinks in the local browser

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, pycharm

I use `ssh -X` to execute a GUI on a remote machine.

This works great, except for one thing:

If I click on a hyperlink in the application, then a browser gets launched on the remote machine.

In my case the application is PyCharm.

How to open the hyperlink in my **local browser**?

[image: open-hyperlink-in-local-browser]

The screenshot is a bit misleading, since the URL is 127.0.0.1. The URL does not matter for this question. All hyperlinks of all applications should open on the local machine.

The remote machine is Ubuntu Linux.

There is a port-forwarding from the local machine `8000` to the remote-server `8000` port.

Comment: The address `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is only meaningful inside the remote machine. How do you want to open it locally? If it's always the same, and if the remote machine is accessible via the network, just open `http://remote-machine:8000` on your side locally.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is a port-forwarding from the local machine `8000` to the remote-server `8000` port. But other URLs like https://example.com should open in the local browser, too.

Comment: That doesn't conflict with doing `http://remote-machine:8000`. Are both machines on the same local network, or is this via the internet and a router?

Comment: @harrymc the remote machine is in most cases a VM/Container running on the same machine, but the solution needs to work for remote machines, too.

Comment: For remote, you could use `http://remote-IP:8000`, as long as the port is forwarded in the remote router. You could even get fancy and use Dynamic DNS for the remote machine if it doesn't have a static IP.

Comment: @harrymc the problem is: I don't want to launch the browser on the remote machine, I want to launch the browser on my machine. But since the URL is in a GUI which gets executed on the remote-machine, the remote machine launches a browser. The example (127.0.0.1) is misleading. This question is not about port-forwarding.

Comment: So the question is only about how to block the automatic launching of the browser on the remote computer? Isn't there such setting in the IDE you are using (and what is this IDE)?

Comment: @harrymc the IDE is PyCharm, but the solution should work for all applications.

Comment: I don't see a solution for all apps that doesn't replace the browser by an application/script that massages the link and sends it to your computer. What you really need is an IDE that works on your computer and does remote debugging.

Comment: Which operating systems for local & remote computers?

Answer (score 2):

When you run a command on a remote machine with `ssh -X`, any commands run are run on the remote machine but displayed on your current display.  Therefore, in order for this to work at all, you'd need to have the following conditions:

1. Your browser on the local machine would need to register itself with the X server in some way to be discoverable.
2. You'd need to set the `BROWSER` environment variable on the remote machine to a program that would query the X server and signal your local browser to open the page using some X11-specific IPC mechanism.

However, I'm not aware of any browser which supports this configuration.  It is theoretically possible to do yourself, but it would require a bunch of custom code to interact with the X server.

You could alternately use the SFTP editing feature of a local editor plus a remote shell to work instead, which might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a solution for all apps that doesn't replace the browser by an application/script that massages the link and sends it to your computer.

Another solution is to compile and debug the project on your local computer
as much as possible, and only copy it to the target machine when it is
working reasonably.

The last solution that I can see is using a debugger that can debug remotely
on the remote computer. As you are using PyCharm, see if the following
help articles fit your case:

- [Remote Debugging with PyCharm﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html)
- [Run/Debug Configuration: Python Debug﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python-remote-debug.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following is far from a ready solution (I don't have enough knowledge about Linux / Unix GUIs to provide one), but it is conceptually clean (if you are able to figure out the GUI part on the server yourself).

A while ago, I had a web project which just consisted of a few hand-crafted pages. As simple as it was, I wanted each change to be immediately reflected in the browser display as soon as I saved the page. I solved this problem basically following the procedure outlined [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome).

So what does this have to do with your question? Well, you could use the same techniques as VSCode to remote-control Chrome: The basic idea is to start a "debugger" Chrome on your local PC, which will listen for "debugging" queries. Then, your remote machine could use the Chrome debugging protocol to send the link to be opened to the "debugger" Chrome on your local PC, and to have it opened there.

The first step is easy. Just start Chrome with certain additional options on your local PC, e.g.

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

The difficult part (for me) would be reconfiguring the remote system. There must be a mechanism which tells the system or application what happens when you click a link. You would have to change that configuration: Instead of opening the browser on the remote system, the link would have to be embedded into a remote debugging packet (i.e. command), and that command would have to be forwarded to the "debugger" Chrome instance on your local PC.

You didn't write which sort of window manager / GUI you have running on the remote server, so nobody can tell you how to change the system-wide configuration there (for example, I have no clue how to tell KDE or Gnome how to open a link, but I am fairly sure that it differs between the two). Plus, there might be applications which have their own configuration mechanism telling them how links should be opened. Again, I have no clue regarding PyCharm, so I can't help you with that either.

Let's assume you have solved that problem. Then you would tell the remote server system or application, respectively, to run a script which does the following when you activate a link:

(a) Construct an appropriate debugger packet / command for Chrome, and

(b) Send this packet to the Chrome instance on your local PC.

[This page](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) is a starting point about the Chrome Debugging Protocol (CDP). Among others, it states how you can open URLs in a new tab via a HTTP endpoint in a remote-controlled Chrome instance. Notably, have a look at the end of the page, section `GET /json/new?{url}`.

As for (b), you could use wget or cURL, for example, to send that query / command to the Chrome instance on your local PC.

As a final note, please be aware that Chrome remote debugging definitely works even if the "debugger" Chrome does not run on the same PC as the client which sends / receives the debugger packets / commands, although (for reasons I don't understand) tutorials rarely mention this. I have personally worked with such configurations: In the small project mentioned above, I was editing the source files on a remote Linux system, while Chrome ran on my local PC.